# how to calculate hash rate of your rig?

Tags: mining-hardware, hashpower

First going the easy way, I would use any online calculator but most of these mining calculators require the hash rate of my device. I am unable to find a suitable answer or a guide to easily compute this value for any device given its configurations. Will that be possible?

Scenario:

When I go to these online calculator sites, they again cross question me about the hash rate/ hashing power. I need to determine this value and feed in to these sites so that I can get the desired result. (e.g. [cryptocompare.com](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=4730&HashingUnit=GH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=1293&CostPerkWh=0.12&MiningPoolFee=1)). I want to know whether it is easy to calculate these values with some information about your machine like the processor, GPUs and all, how much time I am gonna run it. I know the calculator sites need the power input of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash rate isn't something you can calculate by a formula; it's determined empirically.  This number has to come from someone who has the same kind of hardware and has measured how many hashes per second it actually performs, for a given hash algorithm.

For SHA256d, used by Bitcoin, you can see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison for hash rate data contributed by many people.  Note that non-specialized hardware (CPU and GPU) are effectively worthless for SHA256d mining because ASICs are many orders of magnitude more efficient.

For purpose-built mining hardware (like ASICs), the manufacturer will usually quote a hash rate that the machine is supposed to be able to achieve.  Of course, you might also want to get user reports, in case the manufacturer's figures are not realistic.

Answer (score 3):

[This website](https://whattomine.com/) allows you to select your GPU / ASIC / etc, and it will tell you the expected hashrate of that hardware for different algorithms.

I can offer no guarantees about the validity of the data they provide though, in general the best way to figure out your hashrate would be to actually run the hardware and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just add each device hash rate and that is all and to be sure juat
Decrement around 12%

This is what I do

Answer (score -1):

Knowing the hash rate is essential for you.

Why?

Your question is like, if I hire a worker, how many hours per day can my worker work?
OK, so you should know the primitive knowledge about your worker.
Such as how strong he is or how many hours he can work or how much cost to work for one day (lunch or rest cost).
Well, you must first measure the worker's default data, or the second step in the work that you work for.
Therefore, knowing the amount of hash of your operation is very necessary.
But you can now enjoy the famous swimming pool charts for each TH/s.
Please calculate [here](https://www.antpool.com/support.htm?m=calculator).

And there is a very nice calculator [here](https://btc.com/tools/mining-calculator), base on every known thing from your rig.

At last, try to find out, which device or rig are you going to buy (to know power cost/maintenance cost and price of the rig).

Comment: Both the links that you provide again ask for my hash rate which I don't know for my machines.     


>*How many hours per day, My worker can work*     



can I not just feed some algorithms different values of time and get different values as output?

Comment: You are not have to wnter the hash rate in those links. Just fill other fields. The calculator tell you the estimated hash rate base on the information you entered.